# Returning a file from a function using FileReader?

Tags: javascript, html, file, return, filereader

I'm using the [NetTutsPlus tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) for uploading image files and viewing them using FileReader.

I have the following JS code, but I'm not able to actually pass on a file as an argument to another function. When I come out of this function and do something like `var file = imageUpload()`, the `file` variable is undefined.

My question is, how can I pass the file around between functions?

```
function imageUpload() {
    ///some code
    /* THIS IS WHERE WE START THE CROPPING PART */
        $('#imgwrapper').imgAreaSelect({ maxWidth: 600, maxHeight: 348, handles: true,onSelectChange: preview });

    //some more code, the message below shows a file object
            console.log("file: "+file);
            return file;
}
```

I'm trying to use [imageAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) with image file upload using ajax.

Comment: Because FileReader is asyncrhonous API you most likely want a callback, not return. However it is not clear in the context of the question what you want to achieve.

Comment: I simply want to pass on the file as an argument to another function. For example, ``var myfile = imageUpload();``

Comment: As you can see your code there is no variable "file" in the first place, so how can you expect to return it? The file must come from somewhere and it is unclear how you expect this file to pop up in your code. If this is specific to some tutorial, then please ask directly from the tutorial author or fill in the necessary code in the question.